# Change the location of the product description WYSIWYG inside the woocommerce products (Backend)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-admin

We want to change the location of the product long_description Metabox  (the  WYSIWYG editor) in the Wordpress/woocommerce backend for the products.

So when adding or editing a product, we want to have the Product Data Metabox directly underneath the title, and after the Product Data Metabox we want to show the editor for the long description.

Is that possbile?
Thanks for help,

Answer (score 0):

you can simply drag the section and move it to down

Comment: Please check this https://wpartisan.me/tutorials/wordpress-how-to-move-the-excerpt-meta-box-above-the-editor, you can find your solution